# Run a Windows command in Perl outside of CGI enviroment

Tags: windows, perl, cgi

I have a specific proprietary application, which is dual use, running "account.exe" in a CGI context (eg from inside a web server) will make account.exe output a HTML page and such. Running "account.exe" outside of CGI context causes account.exe to enable certain command line functions.

Now to the question:
I want to run account.exe outside the CGI context in perl. Have tried with system(1, "command"); have tried with system("start command"), tried with a BAT wrapper that clears (SET VARIABLE=) every enviroment variable that has with CGI to do, but still account.exe "detects" that its run by a web server and outputs its HTML.

How can I run a windows command in a CGI script in perl (using strawberry perl) and making it impossible for the "account.exe" application to detect that the execution originally came from a web server?

Comment: You haven't told us what "account.exe" is.  There's no way anybody can know the answer without that information.

Comment: account.exe is a part of PCOUNTER http://www.pcounter-europe.com

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how account.exe could possibly detect how it was run.

Environment variables is one way; it seems you have already ruled that one out.

Normally processes can see who is their parent and their parent, so that could be other way.

So either you can do a lot of testing until you finally fool the specific technique that the process is using, or you might want to try *sandboxing* to gain more control on what the process can or cannot  see (or do).

Comment: Basically, is there a way to just execute the process in a completely detached way so the account.exe Thinks it was typed into cmd.exe? Using "cmd.exe /C [command]" doesnt help, the [command] is still a Child of cmd.exe and cmd.exe is a Child of the CGI. Theres no need to Catch return values from account.exe, sanity checking is done Before its put into account.exe.